# Rollback not working properly while using sqlalchemy on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, session, sqlalchemy, transactions

I am facing an issue with SQLalchemy's sessions in python. Underlying database - SQL Server.

**What I am trying to do?**

- Insert into parent and child tables(both have an auto-increment PK) as part of one transaction and rollback changes on both if any error occurs else move on with commiting changes.

This is how the pseudo-code looks -

```
session = Session() # get the session from somewhere. (Auto-Commit=false)
try:
    parent = Parent(...)
    session.add(parent)
    session.flush()
    # By now I expect the new ID updated in parent object.
    child = Child(...)
    session.add(child)
    session.flush()
    # raise Exception('abc') -> 
    # In case of this exception I expect no changes to be written to database,
    # but surprisingly after the execution of mere flush I am able see changes written in SQL server.
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()
```

Now when I check out the logger, in case of exception I see these set of queries going in -

```
[20210612 03:43:23:530 base.py:727 INFO] BEGIN (implicit)
[20210612 03:43:23:531 base.py:1234 INFO] INSERT INTO PARENT TABLE
[20210612 03:43:23:534 base.py:1234 INFO] INSERT INTO CHILD TABLE
[20210612 03:43:23:574 base.py:747 INFO] ROLLBACK
```

Any ideas how is this happening and what might be the corrective actions for it?

Please do let me know in case any other detail is required.

Comment: Can you log the exception and its associated traceback inside the `except` block?  Or remove the try/except altogether to obtain this information.  And then [edit] he question to  include it.

Comment: The logger output shows the ROLLBACK, so even though the INSERTs are applied to the transaction they are not committed. That is expected behaviour.

Comment: @GordThompson I was happy with ROLLBACK coming in logger too. But, the inserts are somehow not rolled back. FWIW, I used session.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION') or session.execute('ROLLBACK TRANSACTION') and things just start to work then.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am manually raising an exception 'ABC' (noted as comment in snippet) and this is what I get in traceback too.

Comment: When you say you see the changes in the db after flush but before commit, how are you viewing them, and what is the isolation level?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am viewing them directly from SQL server while the debugger is between flush and commit statements. Isolation level is 'Read Committed'. Also, when I use session.execute(* TRANSACTION) like statements, the query does not execute between flush and commit in SQL server (some sort of read lock) hinting me at a proper transaction being done.